# passing variable to javascript function and using it in document.form?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Database test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
<script>
function validateForm(n)
{
var x=document.forms.SignUp.n.value;

alert("*"+x+"*");

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Just a Database test</h1>
<form name="SignUp" action="http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/connectivity.cgi" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post">
Ename :<input type="text" name="ename" onchange="validateForm('ename');"><br><p id="error_1"></p>
<input type="submit" value="Send">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to pass the user input value by `onchange="validateForm('ename')` but it does not seem to work i dont get anything.

instead if i change function to this then it works but again i need to pass it as varaible from `onchange="validateForm('ename')`.

```
function validateForm(n)
{

alert("*"+n+"*");

}
```

Comment: What? Both those functions are the same!

Comment: The solution is really simple, use an **ID** on your input or pass `this`, and not `document.forms.formName.elementName`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the element itself, which is `this` inside an inline handler:

```
validateForm(this);

function validateForm(elem)
    alert(elem.value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to make it work, without changing your function call:

```
function validateForm(n) {
    var x = document.forms.SignUp[n].value;
    alert("*"+x+"*");
}
```